# PHP ODBC Not Closing Connections

Tags: php, odbc

I have a PHP application that uses the ODBC functions for database access.  My DBA recently discovered that the application is not closings its database connections, resulting in numerous invalid connections that are in a TIME_WAIT state.

We have checked the code and I am doing an odbc_close_all call in every script, plus even if I wasn't then the connection should close at the end of the script anyway.  There are no long running scripts holding on to their connections

Has anyone seen anything like this or have any idea what the issue might be?

PHP version is 5.1.4
Running on Windows Server 2003 R2 Service Pack 2
MySQL database

Comment: Better ask this question over on serverfault.com. Our beloved fellow-admins are probably better suited to tell you all you need to know about TIME_WAIT, SO_REUSEADDR, MaxUserPort and TcpTimedWaitDelay and how to tweak some windows settings to get around the problem. There's most likely nothing wrong with your script. TIME_WAIT indicates that you have indeed closed the connection, but the operating system keeps the address/port for a while on hold. Connection pooling is most likely not what you want, though _sort of_ possible: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-pconnect

Comment: Why are you using ODBC to connect to MySQL to begin with?

Comment: @Charles:  The application connects to two different databases, one of which is MySQL and and the other is Cache.  The Cache database can only be connected to via ODBC, and the original developer decided to just use ODBC for both to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, we stumbled upon several sources that indicated that the issue was `TcpTimedWaitDelay` (thanks VolkerK for the tip). This has helped a good deal, but we are still seeing about 30-40 connections in the `TIME_WAIT` state at any given time.

We are wondering now if anyone has any advice as to whether this behaviour is normal for a Windows Server and if this is as good as it gets, or if there are other avenues worth researching.

Thanks