# .NET Web Service leaving many MySQL connections open with TIME_WAIT

Tags: mysql, .net, database, web-services

I'm wondering what best practice is on this.  I have a webservice which processes a large amount of traffic.  We're going to be doing load testing soon, but I'm wondering if this is going to be a problem.

The webservice has several functions similar to the below (this is the simplest, so I'm using this one as my example).  Each function requires a few queries on a MySQL database.  I'm using a MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver.  The connection string is like this:

"Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=IPADDRESS;Database=DBNAME;UID=BLAH;Pwd=BLAH;"

Each function establishes a new connection (with a USING statement) and reader, runs the query, and closes the connection and reader.

```
Public Function ServerTime() As String
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow

    Using connection As New OdbcConnection(ConnectionString)

        Dim command As OdbcCommand

        command = New OdbcCommand("SELECT NOW()", connection)

        connection.Open()

        Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = command.ExecuteReader

        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                Dim dbtime As String = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()
                DateTime.TryParse(dbtime, now)

            End While
        End If

        reader.Close()
        connection.Close()

    End Using

    Dim t As TimeSpan = now.ToUniversalTime() - New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)
    Dim timestamp As Double = Math.Round(t.TotalMilliseconds)

    Return timestamp.ToString()
End Function
```

This webservice winds up making 2-3 database calls per second under its current load.  Again, not all the calls are from the above example function.  There are many functions far more commonly called than this one, but they all run a database transaction in a similar manner.

Even under its current (much lighter than our goal) load, running netstat on the IIS server shows four hundred or so ports still being held in the TIME_WAIT state.  As I understand it, they stay open for about four minutes.

Is there a better way to handle the database connection that will not result in all these ports being kept open?  I've seen that I can make a registry change to TcpTimedWaitDelay to reduce the four minute wait, but I'm wondering if this problem can be avoided all together rather than band-aided.  This is hurting scalability.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523500/php-odbc-not-closing-connections

Comment: It's definitely a similar problem, though he is using PHP rather than .NET.  He also never found a solution other than changing the TcpTimedWaitDelay, which is not really a solution but a mitigation.  I'm asking if there's a way to modify my .NET code to work around the way the server handles these connections.

Comment: .Close() closes the connection if connection pooling is disabled. Maybe odbc doesnt close it because it wants to re-use it... I dont see any way to modify the code to avoid this...

Comment: Are you using connection pooling?

Comment: Apparently, the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver wasn't doing any connection pooling.  I switched over to using Oracle's [Connector / NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html) and now, it is pooling connections properly and the TIME_WAIT problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver wasn't doing any connection pooling.  I switched over to using Oracle's [Connector / NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html) and now, it is pooling connections properly and the TIME_WAIT problem went away.

The only downside is that if my database moves from MySQL to MS SQL, which may happen in the near future, I'll have to make some minor code changes rather than just changing the connection string.

Oh well.  Problem solved.